# How do I decrease brightness even further on Thinkpad X230?

Tags: linux, thinkpad, intel-graphics, brightness

```
# cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
0
# xbacklight 
0.000000
```

But it's still way too bright for a dark room. I want to be able to gradually reduce backlight to complete off.

On other laptop (ASUS 1015PEM) intel's brightness=0 corresponded to actual turned off backlight. For Acer Extensa 5220 I used `acer_ec.pl` script which used some `/dev/port` magic.

How do I force really dim mode on Thinkpad X230 on Linux?

Comment: Try here: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=178014

Comment: @monsune, This (and most other topics I found on Internet) deals with inability to control brightness using standard means and treat `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` as a reference thing. Backlight control already work for me. But minimum is not minimal enough.